# C program breaking when I input text through a file. But works when I input text through command line

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, terminal, system

**My program will convert C99-style comment in the input text by an equivalent ANSI C comment.**

Note: The program seems to run correctly on other environments, but I have still included the code for thoroughness (along with some expected calls and outputs.)

*I have also attached an image of the issue I described below.*
**Problem**
Firstly, when I run my program on any online terminal, it works fine. When I input text through the terminal, it works. But the moment I enter text through a file input, it breaks.

I tried for hours, and eventually came down to the following screen shot but I don't know why my program is doing this.

As you can see (1), my `incomment` is initialized to 0. However, when I input the file through the terminal, the FIRST time the loop is iterated through, it starts with the value 1, which is causing my program to break.

But in (2), when I input the text through terminal, it starts as 0. (As expected, since it is initialized to 0).

**Additional things I tried:**

1. I also tried to initialize the `incomment` variable to -1, and the first time in the loop and checked `if (incomment == -1) { incomment = 0; }`
2. I tried other terminals like powershell, bash.

BUT! it still evaluates to 1 the first time the loop runs.

The logic seems correct as it does exactly what I expect it to do, I also got the marks for it in my university assignment and works as expected when I input text through bash or even powershell.

I will submit the program and some expected input texts to it below if anyone else wants to check the correctness.

**Expected call #1**

```
// My useful program
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { /* Our main function */
    printf("Hello world!\n"); // print hello
    // done, phew!
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
/* My useful program */
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { /* Our main function */
    printf("Hello world!\n"); /* print hello */
    /* done, phew! */
    return 0;
}
```

**Expected call #2:**

```
//// ***** this code is bad, comment it out *****
// printf("Hello world\n"); /* prints hello world */
// return 0;
// /* done, phew! */
```

**Expected output 2:**

```
/*// ***** this code is bad, comment it out ***** */
/* printf("Hello world\n");  prints hello world  */
/* return 0; */
/*  done, phew!  */
```

[Debugging screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z08P9.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STAR 42
#define FWDSLASH 47
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ch, incomment = 0, slashlast = 0, starlast = 0;
    
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {

    // check if line is in comment
        
        if (incomment)
        {   
            
            // Ignore any other /* combinations
            if (ch == '/')
            {
                if (starlast) {
                    starlast = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                if (slashlast)
                {
                    printf("/");
                }
                slashlast = 1;

            }
            // if newline found, set end */
            else {
                
                if (ch == '*')
                {
                    
                    if (slashlast) {
                        slashlast = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (starlast)
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    starlast = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    if (ch == '\n')
                    {
                        if (starlast)
                        {
                            printf("*");
                            starlast = 0;
                            
                        }
                        else if (slashlast)
                        {
                            printf("/");
                            slashlast = 0;
                            
                        }
                        incomment = 0;
                        printf(" */");
                        putchar(ch);
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (starlast)
                        {
                            printf("*");
                            putchar(ch);
                        }
                        else if (slashlast)
                        {
                            printf("/");
                            putchar(ch);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            putchar(ch);
                        }
                        starlast = 0;
                        slashlast = 0;
                    }
                }
                
                
            }    
        }
        else
        {
            // Not in comment
            
            //Check for // combination and replace with /* combination
            if (ch == FWDSLASH)
            {
                //Two slashes foud
                if (slashlast)
                {
                    incomment = 1;
                    printf("/*");
                    // Done checking for slashes
                    slashlast = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    slashlast = 1;
                }
                
                
            }   
            else
            {
                if (slashlast)
                {
                    // Print the previous slash then print self.
                    printf("/");
                    putchar(ch);
                    slashlast = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    putchar(ch);
                    slashlast = 0;
                }
                
            }

        }

    }
    

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: PSA: `STAR` is just `'*'`. No need for constants or numbers.

Comment: Minor suggestion: instead of separate variables `slashlast` and `starlast`, just track the last character read, itself.  That will simplify your state tracking considerably, and overall be cleaner and clearer.

Comment: I'm not following what manner of feeding your program input is causing it to misbehave.  It reads only from its standard input, so your input choices seem to be either interactive or via redirection, but the program works as expected for me both ways.

Comment: The code in the question does not containing anything that prints the value of `incomment`. Therefore, the output in your image does not come from the posted code. Edit the question to provide a [mre] that contains **exactly** the code that produces **exactly** the output shown. Also, none of your sample inputs, which you seem to call “Expected call” for some reason, contain text that matches the output in the screenshot—they do not contain “not comment” or “Hey”. Prepare one single exact example of sample input (not “expected call”) and the exact output from it.

Comment: For me the program seemt to work as expected when I run it with any of your example input like `./comment < input2.c`. If I add a line `printf("%i", incomment);` as in the screenshot, it starts with `0` as expected. I suggest to [edit] the code in question and add this output. Also copy & paste the command that reproduces the problem with its output to your question *as text*.